# Jibx binding testing against xsd

Tags: java, xsd, jibx, xml-generation

I work on a project that uses jibx for marshalling/unmarshalling xmls. And every time when xsd changes I have to change bindings which I'm ok with.

But what I want is to be sure before deploy that there is no xml such that the xml is xsd-valid and may cause any marshalling/unmarshalling errors. 
Java object model and xsd have different structure, so regenerating binding files is not an option.

Possible ways I see to solve this problem are:

- find a way to validate jibx binding files against xsd set(I couldn't so far)
- generate xml by xsd set and use it in JUnit tests.

So what's the best way to achieve that goal, what libraries/tools could be helpful?

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to completely test the binding against the xsd. The best approach for what you want is to use the xsd to generate multiple sample xml documents and use those in your unit tests.